# Keep getting a handling error. Causing my program to break

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack

```
void push(char name, int key)
{
    Node *character = NULL;
    character->link = tos;
    name = character->data;
    key = character->precedence;
    push(character);
};
```

My my two exceptions:

```
First-chance exception at 0x011460C2 in Program Assignment 2new.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000008.
Unhandled exception at 0x011460C2 in Program Assignment 2new.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000008.
```

Also `tos` is a pointer already defined earlier in my code.

Comment: You're declaring a pointer, assigning it a value of NULL, then immediately dereferencing it. What are you trying to do here? It's difficult to tell without seeing your other code.

Comment: push(char, int): creates a new node and places it on the TOS(top of stack), you will need to provide variables for the char and int parameters

Answer (score 0):

You declare a pointer 'character' of type Node and make it null. You never actually call 'New' on that pointer. You must call new to create an instance of character otherwise character->link doesn't have a valid memory location and you will get exceptions.

*Remember to call delete too to give the space back.

Comment: Adding new in front of Node* character only gives me a different error of a missing semicolon

Comment: @VontaTreiBrinson That's because that's the wrong place. Try `Node* character = new Node;`. And get a decent book to study from.

Comment: What book would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

```
    void push(char name, int key)
    {
        Node *character = new (std::nothrow) Node;
        if(0 != character){
            character->link = tos;
            name = character->data;
            key = character->precedence;
            push(character);
        }
        else{
             //Give an error message
       }
    }
```

Is how I would re-write what you do have to avoid some errors.

Originally you set character to NULL, and then attempted to access it which is undefined behavior.